# Java DataOutputStream alternative in Go

Tags: go, serialization, encoding, dataoutputstream

I have a few lines in Java

```
out.write(223);
out.writeBytes("something");
out.writeInt(434);
```

So far I did not seem to find what is the alternative of Java `DataOutputStream` in Go and did not find similar functions to .write .writebytes. writeint. I'd really appreciate some help :) Also, it would be great if you could show me the full code on how to connect to specific IP and port and output **bytes**, integers and other data to that IP, like with `DataOutputStream`.

Comment: Please note that [the language is called Go](https://golang.org/doc/faq#go_or_golang). Also note that you should not include the name of the language to the question's title.

Answer (score 1):

Go, luckily, has a more fine-grained approach.

You have the [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) package in the Go's stdlib, which is able to format integer data types as binaries — both in little-endian (as that `DataOutputStream` appears to do) and big-endian.
Start with `encoding/binary.LittleEndian.PutUint*` methods.
They place encoded bytes into a slice, which you can then write the usual way (see below).

Everything in Go, which is able to "ingest bytes" implements the special interface, [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer); files and TCP sockets to this as well.

So you write what you call "bytes" — opaque lumps of bytes are usually operated using so-called byte slices, `[]byte`, in Go — directly to any object which implemets `io.Writer`.
To write an integer value, you first encode it to a byte slice and then write the same way.

Strings are a more interesting topic. I see no mention in the docs on `DataOutputStream` about how it deals with character encoding, so I have no idea what to suggest.
Still, you can write any Go string to an `io.Writer` by calling [`io.WriteSting`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#WriteString) helper function.

---

Regarding your

> … it would be great if you could show me the full code on how to …

please, read [this](https://whathaveyoutried.com/).

To get started, please do this:

1. Complete [the Tour](https://tour.golang.org).
2. Read ["Effective Go"](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html).

This will have you covered with, like, 90%, of the necessary knowledge.
The rest can be obtained by reading [the Go Blog](https://blog.golang.org/index); in particular, these articles:

- [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro)
- [Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](https://blog.golang.org/slices)
- [Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings)
- [Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants).